# How do i select data in a table?

Tags: sql

So ive got a table named artists and it has multiple places of origin like UK , US , Ireland. What command would i put in if i just wanted to select the other countries excluding UK.

Comment: Hi @KishanKotecha, welcome to SO, could you mention the column names of your table along with few example records

Comment: Colum names - Id , name , start_year , end_year , origin , type , gender. Example records - Massive attack ( name )1987 ( start year)  null (end year) , united kingdom ( origin) , group(type) , null (gender)

Comment: You may start by reading: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give all the info from `artists` table excluding records having `origin` value as 'UK'

```
Select * from artists where origin <> 'UK';
```

Comment: When i try and put that into this syntax it gives me an error, SELETC * FROM artists WHERE name LIKE 'R%' SELECT * FROM artists WHERE origin <> ' UK '; - i get error 1064

Comment: Could you tell what exactly do you want to search for? Your query seems like you want name starting with R ? But you have added additional query which I mentioned.

Comment: I want to find all the artists that are called R and also who are not from the United Kingdom

Comment: You can AND to join two conditions in a query so the query will change as  : `Select * from artists where origin <> 'UK' and name like 'R%';`

Comment: please accept the answer if this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the SELECT statement to 'key in' what data you want, then use `FROM` to highlight the specific data you want. The `*` means all data `FROM -----`. Use `WHERE` to add a condition and I would recommend just using not as you are only using a column value so all together it would look like

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE origin NOT 'UK';
```

Comment: Please edit your reply and correct the statement. That is going to fail on say MS SQL server and postgreSQL at least. Try using <> instead of NOT.